# Laravel Nova Value Metric For Later Days

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Laravel Nova suggests [Value Metrics](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html#value-metrics) and the ranges are for previous days until today. It is okay while we are using `created_at` as the default `date` column to show the result.
But, sometimes we need to show the result based on a `date` column that is able to contain a value for later days. For example, we may need to calculate the `sum` `amount` of a resource based on its `settlement_date` which might be tomorrow.

```php
    /**
     * Calculate the value of the metric.
     *
     * @param NovaRequest $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->sum(
            $request,
            Settlement::where('status', 'PENDING'), 'amount', 'settlement_date')->format('0,0');
    }

    /**
     * Get the ranges available for the metric.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function ranges()
    {
        return [
            'TODAY' => 'Today',
            7 => 'Week',
            30 => '30 Days',
            60 => '60 Days',
            365 => '365 Days',
        ];
    }
```

**WHAT IF**, I want to know the value of this query for the later days like tomorrow.
Something like this query does not work, any idea?

```php
return $this->sum(
            $request,
            Settlement::where('status', 'PENDING')->where('settlement_date', Carbon::tomorrow()), 'amount', 'settlement_date')->format('0,0');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using [Trends Metric](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html#trend-metrics), like this:

```php
    /**
     * Calculate the value of the metric.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        $settlement  = new \App\Models\VmsSettlement\Settlement;

        $twoDaysAgoSum      = $settlement->where('status', 'PENDING')->where('settlement_date', Carbon::today()->subDays(2)->toDateString())->sum('amount');
        $yesterdaySum       = $settlement->where('status', 'PENDING')->where('settlement_date', Carbon::today()->subDay()->toDateString())->sum('amount');
        $todaySum           = $settlement->where('status', 'PENDING')->where('settlement_date', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->sum('amount');
        $tomorrowSum        = $settlement->where('status', 'PENDING')->where('settlement_date', Carbon::today()->addDay()->toDateString())->sum('amount');
        $twoDaysLaterSum    = $settlement->where('status', 'PENDING')->where('settlement_date', Carbon::today()->addDays(2)->toDateString())->sum('amount');

        return (new TrendResult)->trend([
             Carbon::today()->subDays(2)->toDateString() . ' (2 days ago)'   => $twoDaysAgoSum,
             Carbon::today()->subDay()->toDateString() . ' (Yesterday)'            => $yesterdaySum,
             Carbon::today()->toDateString() . ' (Today)'                          => $todaySum,
             Carbon::today()->addDay()->toDateString() . ' (Tomorrow)'             => $tomorrowSum,
             Carbon::today()->addDays(2)->toDateString() . ' (2 days later)' => $twoDaysLaterSum,
        ])->format('0,0');
    }

    /**
     * Get the ranges available for the metric.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function ranges()
    {
        return [
            //30 => '30 Days',
            //60 => '60 Days',
            //90 => '90 Days',
        ];
    }
```